# Is there a way to react to Control Panel changes to an order?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

One of the major issues I have been having with my current project is how to reconcile changes to an order in the control panel (product amounts and the like). I thought I might be able to react to Order events but it would seem that the `ADD_LINE_ITEM_EVENT` and the like are only called from the user-facing side (ie a Cart).

I need to be able to update quantities available from the changes to the Order in the Control Panel, any suggestions?

An Example:

Jane Doe orders product A, our friendly staff member gets notified and speaks with Jane to complete the transaction. Jane decides she actually wants 2 of product A and heck, why not product B. Friendly staff updates her order, redoes the authorization, captures it, and thinks they are done. Now though, we have not updated our stocks for product A and B of which there is a limited amount and we can now potentially oversell!

What are we supposed to do here?